# Can fields be removed from an ongoing cursor in PL/SQL Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a massive insert from a 'temporary file', so I'm using a cursor to modify some values. I added a field based on a 'row_number()' column to get a next number created for each record. That record & my 'lot number' would constitute the new lot value (e.g. for lot 'Alpha', I would have 'Alpha01', 'Alpha02', 'Alpha03', &c.).

But I don't know how to remove that extra-column after I've done the changes, so I don't get an issue with the insert process (my cursor now has more columns than the original file).

So the current code reads:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
-- Array of lot numbers & how I want to name them --
TYPE VARR_LOTN IS TABLE OF VARCHAR(8);
VAR_LOTN VARR_LOTN;
TOTAL INTEGER;
-- Application-relevant variables --
MAX_VAL NUMBER := &&Maximum_Values.;
VAR_MMCU VARCHAR(12) := '&&Branch.';
VAR_ITM NUMBER := '&&Item.';
VAR_DATE NUMBER := TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYDDD') - 1900000;
VAR_TIME NUMBER := TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24MISS');
-- This section is the cursor I'm creating --
-- Note the Row_Number() aggregate function, which I want to use as counter --
CURSOR VAR_LOTN_C IS
    SELECT LPAD(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY IOITM), 2, 0) IOID, T1.* FROM TESTDTA.F4108 T1
    WHERE IOITM = VAR_ITM AND IOLOTS = ' ' AND TRIM(IOMCU) = VAR_MMCU AND IOMMEJ >= TO_CHAR(SYSDATE + 365, 'YYYYDDD') - 1900000 AND ROWNUM <= MAX_VAL;
-- I'm having somre trouble understanding how the %RowType attribute works, & which others are available --
VARC_LOTN VAR_LOTN_C%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
    VAR_LOTN := VARR_LOTN('Alpha', 'Beta', 'Gamma', 'Delta');
    TOTAL := VAR_LOTN.COUNT;

    FOR T1 IN 1 .. TOTAL
        LOOP
            -- I'm fetching the cursor into the "variable" --
            OPEN VAR_LOTN_C;
                FETCH VAR_LOTN_C INTO VARC_LOTN;
            CLOSE VAR_LOTN_C;
                -- This is why I added column IOID, to have records as 'Alpha01', 'Alpha02', &c --
                VARC_LOTN.IOLOTN := T1 || VARC_LOTN.IOID;

                -- Other relevant variable changes... --
                VARC_LOTN.IODOCO := 0;
                VARC_LOTN.IODCTO := NULL;
                -- UA0
                VARC_LOTN.IOUA01 := VAR_DATE;
                VARC_LOTN.IOUA02 := 0;
                VARC_LOTN.IOUA03 := 0;
                VARC_LOTN.IOUA04 := VAR_DATE;
                VARC_LOTN.IOUA05 := 0;
                VARC_LOTN.IOUA06 := VAR_DATE;
                -- UB0
                VARC_LOTN.IOUB01 := 0;
                VARC_LOTN.IOUB02 := 0;
                VARC_LOTN.IOUB03 := 0;
                VARC_LOTN.IOUB04 := 0;
                VARC_LOTN.IOUB05 := 0;
                VARC_LOTN.IOUB06 := 0;
                -- AUDIT
                VARC_LOTN.IOUSER := 'Me';
                VARC_LOTN.IOPID := 'SQL'; 
                VARC_LOTN.IOUPMJ := VAR_DATE;
                VARC_LOTN.IOTDAY := VAR_TIME;
                -- ***In here is where I need to get rid of column IOID, so I can insert the batch I just created into the table. I cannot insert it now because this column does not exist in table F4108, I created it only for my own numbering.-*** --
                {{{ALTER TABLE VARC_LOTN DROP COLUMN IOID; or something like that...}}}

            -- Here I insert the final fetch --
            INSERT INTO TESTDTA.F4108
                VALUES VARC_LOTN;

        END LOOP;
END;
```

I'm not finding if it's possible to do those changes, & the other options that come to my head are not really user-friendly (entering all the columns one by one...).

Do you know if that is feasible?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Columns can not be removed from cursor at runtime.

But I think you dont need your column `IOID` in cursor.

Use following cursor query:

```
SELECT T1.*  -- temoved row_number from here
FROM TESTDTA.F4108 T1
WHERE IOITM = VAR_ITM AND IOLOTS = ' ' 
AND TRIM(IOMCU) = VAR_MMCU AND IOMMEJ >= TO_CHAR(SYSDATE + 365, 'YYYYDDD') - 1900000 
AND ROWNUM <= MAX_VAL
ORDER BY IOITM; -- ADDED THIS order by clause
```

You need to declare one local variable:

```
LOCAL_VARIABLE NUMBER := 0;
```

And where `IOID` is used, you can replace it with:

```
LOCAL_VARIABLE := LOCAL_VARIABLE + 1;
VARC_LOTN.IOLOTN := T1 || LPAD(LOCAL_VARIABLE, 2, 0);
```

It will achieve the same result as your code and also cursor will be free from extra column.

Cheers!!

Comment: Also, You can use `TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,12), 'YYYYDDD') - 1900000 ` instead of `TO_CHAR(SYSDATE + 365, 'YYYYDDD') - 1900000 ` for accurate result

Comment: But I would need to do a loop, isn't it. Local Variable need to be consecutive.